# Correct pronunciation of Helouys on

Tags: prononciation, ancien-français

as medieval re-enactor, I am trying to find evidence for the correct "in period" pronunciation of this name. HELOUYS. It is documented in Paris in 1292 or thereabouts. However, it is used within the context of a Norman persona in Waterford Ireland.

Comment: This is really far back in time, and even harder if a "Norman persona" is at stake :-)

Comment: Any more details?  First name, last name, man, woman?  Was it someone who spoke French, if any other languages, and lived in Ireland?

Comment: This name is a variant spelling of "Héloïse". The book [The Letters of Abelard and Heloise](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Letters_of_Abelard_and_Heloise/tqD9sIXd1vMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=helouys+et+abelard&pg=PT6&printsec=frontcover) (found in Google books) contains  "The rubric, the two lines in red above the miniature, is explanatory. It reads: Comment Helouys labeesse / Entrodit Pierres Abalart (How Peter Abelard instructs Heloise)." So now, we just have to figure out the pronunciation of Héloïse around 1300 in French.

Comment: A possibly related question (about the sound of "ou" in older versions of French—although not as far back as you are asking about): [How was the grapheme "ou" pronounced in 1614?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50833)

Answer (score 3):

I'm nowhere near an expert on the pronunciation of Old French, but since nobody else seems to be answering this, I will. Maybe this will encourage somebody to correct me.

I can't say exactly how *Helouys* was pronounced, but I can give something that's probably good enough for medieval re-enactment.

The "h" should be pronounced /h/, because Old French pronounced the letter "h" when it came from German (but not Latin) and *Helouys* was derived from German *Helewidis.*

The "s" should be pronounced [s], since Old French words couldn't end with [z]. Ending [z]s were devoiced and converted to [s].

There should clearly be three syllables. The third vowel was probably [i]. The second vowel was probably [o] or [ɔ]. If you're speaking English, I'd recommend pronouncing it [o] since English speakers have a lot of trouble with the combination [ɔ.i]. And the first vowel must have been [ɛ] or [e]. Since English speakers can't say [e] without making it a diphthong, I'd recommend using [ɛ].

So this gives /hɛlois/.